# How can I overlap the Angular Material items

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 7 and Angular Material.
I would like to overlap the materials but it does not work.
When I clicked button the side-nav will open and the height is same as button's one. However I would like to be the side-nav's height that I set up.

I used the container's position on CSS but it didn't work.
So how could I solve this problem?

Comment: You must share code with you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the height. Either by using Flexbox or by setting fullscreen on the layout container.

Here you can find a more detailed description:
https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/material-2-sticky-footer-mat-sidenav/

And here the final look:
https://cankattwinkel.github.io/material-2-sticky-footer-mat-sidenav/

A link to the source code is included.